# logstash-output-solr_http plugin installing on logstash 5.4.0

Tags: logstash

I'm a beginner with the Logstash and Ruby.

```
C:\Windows\system32>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.1 (2017-01-11 patchlevel 0) [java]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/A.aminian/.gem/jruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/bin/jruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/A.aminian/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-java-1.8
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems
     - C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

and the command of "bundle install" in directory of "C:\logstash-5.4.0" installs all dependencies. I set some proxies for http and https protocols:

set https_proxy=https://...
an http_proxy proxy is defined in .m2/setting.xml (maven setting).

I followed all the steps mentioned in [sorl_http](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-solr_http)

when I ran following command, these errors were launched:

```
C:/logstash-5.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/rubyzip-1.1.7/lib/zip.rb:35: warning: ObjectSpace impacts performance. 
Installing...
ERROR: Installation Aborted, message: undefined method `each_pair' for "C:/logstash-5.4.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0":String
Did you mean?  each_char
```

Answer (score 0):

Main reason of this error was related to the compatibility of various versions of logstash and jruby. In the last release note of JRUBY (jruby-9.1.10.0), it`s mentioned that "Ruby 2.x compatibility". With previous version of jruby, logstash-plugin was confusing to diagnose correct path of related gem files.